# jmeter HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,Non HTTP response message: Connection refused Error

Tags: apache, xampp, jmeter

I am working to JMeter for testing the load.I am using Amazon Server.when I test the load to 400 Concurrent users, I am getting the error message

```
HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,Non HTTP response message: Connection refused
```

Till the 400 Threads Request, it is working fine and provide us the response.

We are using Xammp and apache server.Can anyone help me out?

Thanks
Mitesh

Comment: In simple words your server capacity is 400 threads/users. I assume tuning was done on server side and JMeter best practices were followed

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that your Apache is configured to accept as many as 400+ concurrent users. Here are [instructions](http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_optimize_apache_web_server_for_maximum_concurrent_connections_or_increase_max_clients_in_apache) on calculating and setting.
2. Make sure that your JMeter is configured to produce as many as 400+ concurrent users. Here is the [guide on proper JMeter tuning](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips).
3. Make sure that your Apache and JMeter systems are not overloaded and have enough spare CPU, RAM, Network and Disk IO, disk space, swap, etc. You can use [PerfMon JMeter Plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for monitoring systems health.