# Jmeter Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, jmeter

I am Load testing my .Net web application using Jmeter.
For different threads and ramp-up time period, I am getting the same exception everytime:

```
Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException/Non HTTP response message: Connect to server failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

I tried with 1000 threads with 100 seconds ramp-up time - 999 threads finished

I tried with 1000 threads with 500 seconds ramp-up time - 999 threads finished

I tried with 900 threads with 900 seconds ramp-up time - 899 threads finished

I tried with 750 threads with 75 seconds ramp-up time - 649 threads finished

After 4.50 seconds of test start, I am getting this one exception for all above tests with the maximum Response time of 21000 ms.

In Http Request Defaults - I have set Timeout(milliseconds) Connect to 60000

Is this something with Jmeter or my application Server?

Comment: The test is running fine without errors for 500 threads with 50 seconds ramp-up time, completing 500 threads

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664979/getting-an-error-response-code-non-http-response-code-org-apache-http-conn-ht   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816792/jmeter-http-response-code-org-apache-http-conn-httphostconnectexception-non-htt Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your application gets overloaded hence cannot properly respond in a timely fashion when virtual users number exceeds 500 so it looks like you discovered the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)

The next step would be to find out the reason which can be in:

1. Incorrect [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) configuration for high loads, check out [Tuning IIS 10.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/role/web-server/tuning-iis-10) and follow the steps to increase maximum number of connections, introduce caching, etc.
2. It might be the lack of resources (CPU, RAM, Network sockets or ports, etc.) on operating system level, I would recommend monitoring baseline OS counters (including IIS-related ones) it can be done using either [Windows PerfMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/perfmon) application or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
3. It is also possible that your application code itself is not too good, i.e. it's using [inefficient algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) or operating large entities. You can re-run your test with a [profiler tool](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/07/01/11-code-profiling-and-performance-tools.aspx) to identify the slowest part(s) of your application which will be the first target(s) to refactor/fix